# SQL Sequence increasing/resetting based on crtieria

Tags: sql, sequence, vertica

I'm trying to write a query in SQL but have hit a brick wall.

My results table looks similar to the below:

```
Category    Date
1234    15/07/2014
1234    17/07/2014
1234    29/07/2014
1234    31/07/2014
1234    02/08/2014
1234    04/08/2014
1234    06/08/2014
1211    17/07/2014
1211    06/08/2014
1211    08/08/2014
```

I'm trying to create a sequence which resets when the difference in dates is greater than 2 aswell as unique to the category as follows:

```
Category    Date    Sequence
1234    15/07/2014  1
1234    17/07/2014  2
1234    29/07/2014  1
1234    31/07/2014  2
1234    02/08/2014  3
1234    04/08/2014  4
1234    06/08/2014  5
1211    17/07/2014  1
1211    06/08/2014  1
1211    08/08/2014  2
```

Comment: Thanks marc - Vertica is the database I'm using

Comment: This is something that you would need to use a window function for and apply after the data is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished using the [`CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/TimeSeries/CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENTAnalytic.htm) function. Thanks to [sKwa & scutter](http://vertica-forums.com/viewtopic.php?p=6439#p6439) for the help!

```
SELECT Category, 
       Date, 
       RANK() 
         OVER ( 
           PARTITION BY Category, seq 
           ORDER BY Date) 
FROM   (SELECT Category, 
               Date, 
               CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(DATEDIFF(day, prev_Date, Date) > 2) 
                 OVER ( 
                   PARTITION BY Category 
                   ORDER BY Date) AS seq 
        FROM   (SELECT *, 
                       LAG(Date, 1) 
                         OVER ( 
                           PARTITION BY Category 
                           ORDER BY Date) prev_Date 
                FROM   test) q) q2 
ORDER  BY Category, 
          Date;
```